# Plotting two side by side different plots in base leads to the same plot being drawn twice

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting in base two histograms:

```
#grid
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
#plot1
with(new_train, plot(hist(Elevation)))
#plot2
with(new_test, plot(hist(Elevation)))
```

[image: siede by side plots]

data is different! Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are making a call to "plot".

```
#grid
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
#plot1
with(new_train, hist(Elevation))
#plot2
with(new_test, hist(Elevation))
```

Comment: Omg, you are right, I didn't need to call plot. Thank you!